# Matching a required string and assigning a portion to regex grouping in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have the following snippet of code:

```
names[count]=osd.0
for line_2 in osd_tree.stdout:
   match_2 = re.search(r"%s*(\bup\b|\bdown\b)" % names[count], line_2)
      if match_2:
      status.append(match_2.group(1))
print status
```

I am looping through he following lines:

```
# id    weight  type name       up/down reweight
-1      40.25   pool default   
-3      40.25           rack unknownrack
-2      10.6                    host NC-T920-SAN-10-00
1       1.1                             osd.1   up      1
2       1                               osd.2   up      1
3       1.1                             osd.3   up      1
4       1.1                             osd.4   up      1
5       1.1                             osd.5   up      1
0       1.1                             osd.0   up      1
24      0.8                             osd.24  up      1
25      1.1                             osd.25  up      1
26      1.1                             osd.26  up      1
27      1.1                             osd.27  up      1
```

In my mind, this regex should be looking for a line that has "osd.0" any characters inbetwix and (up or down). It will then assign (up or down) to group(1).  I am not getting a match it appears.  At least I should say that the return from print status is [].

As an aside, I would also like to word bound the initial variable in the expression so that osd.1 and osd.17 don't create the same match, but when I had the following code the following error resulted.  It seems obvious that the syntax is not correct:

```
match_2 = re.search(r"\b%s\b*(\bup\b|\bdown\b)" % names[count], line_2)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./snmp_osd_check.py", line 44, in <module>
  number, names, status = get_osds()
File "./snmp_osd_check.py", line 33, in get_osds
  match_2 = re.search(r"\b%s\b*(\bup\b|\bdown\b)" % names[count], line_2)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 142, in search
  return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 242, in _compile
  raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat
```

Any ideas?

To the comments below, I have the following code in place and it working fine else where:

```
 for line in osds.stdout:
  match = re.search(r"(\bosd\.[0-9]*\b)", line)
  if match:
     names.append(match.group(1))
     number.append(count)
```

If there is no match, it skips the line and moves on, if there is a match, it assigns group(1) to the list.  I don't mean to argue the point, but I am trying to understand why this use case is different.

Comment: `status.append(match_2.group(1))` is not in the if statement

Comment: I thought about that, but I also wondered if it has to be.  There is only instance of the match text, so if that line is encountered that variable will have value, if not it will not.  At that point I am just hand picking the grouping from that matched line.  Is that not accurate?

Comment: If you don't have a match that code will fail because you're trying to get group 1 of a None match. It's not the problem you're encountering but it is a problem.

Comment: Maybe useful to you: `line.split()[-3].split('.')[1]`.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing in your regular expression to match the space between `osd.0` and `up`, and your use of the `*` quantifier is inappropriate.

For example, `osd.0*` means match `osd` followed by one of any character (except a newline), followed by the character `0` zero or more times.

If you use `re.escape(names[count])` then non-alphanumeric characters will be escaped to prevent them being treated as special regex characters, i.e. `osd.0` will be treated as `osd\.0`.

Try adding `\s` so that zero or more space characters can be matched

```
r"\b%s\s*\b(up|down)\b"
```

Comment: Thanks Mike.  That is a small change that makes a big difference.  You also helped me clean up the syntax of using the /b borders in conjunction with the logical or.  That was a great help.

Comment: @user2242146. If you're happy with it, please accept this answer by clicking the tick (check mark) on the left under the vote arrows.